# Notepad++ add string to a certain line

Tags: windows, notepad++, line

Is there any way I can add a string to the beginning of a certain line in Notepad++?

For example, I want to add a string to line 23 and then go to a new line. Is that possible?

EDIT:

Input:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

Expected result:

```
text 1
text 2
ADDED LINE
text 3
```

I know i could just copy and paste the string there, but I have to do this for multiple files.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52781921/edit) and add input file and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:.+(\R)){23}`
- Replace with: `$0added line$1`
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- BE SURE YOUR CURSOR IS POSITIONNED AT THE BEGINNING OF THE FIRST LINE, then
- <kbd>Replace</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (?:       : start non capture group
    .+      : 1 or more any character but newline
    (\R)    : group 1, any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
  ){23}     : non capture group must appears 23 times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          : the whole match
added line  : line to be added
$1          : content of group 1 (i.e. linebreak)
```